# My Visual Studio work items show Microsoft Services in the potential assignee list

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

How do I remove these strange services from the list of available assignees?

[image: This is in Visual Studio in the work item]

Comment: To clarify, I am using Team Foundation Services (online), not Team Foundation Server. I feel like there should be an option on the visualstudio.com site but I've been looking for hours and can't find anything

Answer (score 1):

I have got the same result as you. Not sure it's by designed or a bug due to recent escalation of VSTS.

You could  submit a Bug in this  place [Develop Community-Team Services](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/21/index.html) and will get quick response by develop team.

For now as a workaround, you could do the assign to option of the work item in the **web**. It works well without those annoying Microsoft services.

[image]

Comment: Bug submitted to Microsoft. Does anyone else have suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

This is an expected behavior. Refer to this link for details: [Unexpected entries appear in "Assigned To" list in Team Explorer when connecting to a VSTS team project.](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/2925575/unexpected-entries-appear-in-assigned-to-list-in-team-explorer-when-connecting-to-a-vsts-team-project)

> Posted by Sean [MSFT] on 7/15/2016 at 7:10 AM
>
> This is as designed for VSTS if you are connecting from VS. The reason
>   you don't see the identities from Web Access when searching is because
>   the data source is different. It's connecting to our identity service
>   which can filter down results to only the identities which are users.
>   You can still manually type in one of those identities above and the
>   work item will save fine.
>
> The VS client uses can only use local metadata, which means it doesn't
>   have the extra information that the identity service has for
>   determining if it should show a user or not in the picker.
>
> I'm sorry for the confusion, and hope this feedback is helpful.

Comment: Not so useful, is there any way to fix the data source?

Comment: @JustinPark I'm afraid that the answer is no since it is just an expected behavior base on current design.